# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI, No action was found on the controller that matches the request

Tags: ajax, api, url-routing

I have gone through few answers but haven't found an answer to my problem.

**my ajax request**

```
$.ajax({     
 url: "api/Company/GetQuarters/" + STARTQ+ '/' + CURRQ,
 type: "GET",
 ...
});
```

**my api**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetQuarters(int start,int end)
    {
     ...
    }
```

**routes**

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "GetQuarters",
        "Company/GetQuarters/{start}/{end}",
        defaults: new { start = RouteParameter.Optional, end = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I keep getting the error message

**error message**

> No action was found on the controller 'Company' that matches the
>   request.

How can I fix ?

EDIT: The project structure is Test->API->CompanyAPI.cs; Test->Global.asax
In Global.asax

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      ....

     routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/",
            defaults:new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, Action="GET, POST"  });
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "GetQuarters",
            "Company/GetQuarters/{start}/{end}",
            defaults: new { start = RouteParameter.Optional, end=RouteParameter.Optional });
   ....

    }
```

Controller:

```
public class CompanyController : ApiController
{
 [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetQuarters(int start,int end)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the "api/" prefix from your Ajax call.
I assume the action you show is in a Company controller?

Comment: yes sellotape, public HttpResponseMessage GetQuarters(int start,int end) is in CompanyController. When I remove "api/" then I get error message:No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost/test/Company/GetQuarters/56/64

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the rest of your route configuration (well the ones that might affect this), and the attributes and declaration of your controller. Also a comment on your project structure; e.g. are your MVC and Web API controllers in the same project? What versions of MVC / Web API?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's just that your **GetQuarters** route registration doesn't start with "api/", i.e.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "GetQuarters",
        "api/Company/GetQuarters/{start}/{end}",
        defaults: new { start = RouteParameter.Optional, end=RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: jamesk, I've tried that too, no that's not the problem, I still get the "No action was found on the controller 'Company' that matches the request"

Comment: And if you move the default route after the GetQuarters one? It's normally there to catch anything your custom routes don't match, at the moment it's the first thing to match.

Comment: Are you registering the web api routes against the 'RouteTable.Routes' rather than the 'GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes'?

Comment: jamesk,  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Comment: Ok, swap the registration to the appropriate WebApi config approach. Depending on your WebApi version use 'GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApi.Register)' ([see](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api)) or 'WebApi.Regiser(GlobalConfiguration.Config)'.